# How to get response variable from viewModelScope Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, response

in my Android project i need to use one of my viewmodel's response in another fragment. But whenever i try to get that value it is always null. I tried to get it from its own fragment with livedata and it works!.  But it is not same for another fragment. Here my viewmodel code that has the response ;

```
package com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.ui.auth

import android.content.Intent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelInject
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.repositories.AuthorizeSessionRepository
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.repositories.GetDomainRepository
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.repositories.GetUserRepository
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.data.network.responses.GetUserResponse
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.ui.home.HomeActivity
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class AuthViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor (
   private val authorizeSessionRepository: AuthorizeSessionRepository,
   private val getDomainRepository: GetDomainRepository,
   private val getUserRepository: GetUserRepository
):ViewModel() {

    var userName :String?=null
    var password: String ? = null
    val isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    private val location = "bexfatest.saasteknoloji.com"
    val isSuccessfull = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    var getUserResponseMutable = MutableLiveData<GetUserResponse>()
    fun onClickUserLogin(view: View){
        val sessionID = 0
        val authorityID = 0
        val loginType = "System"

        viewModelScope.launch {
                if(!(userName==null||password==null)){
                isLoading.value = true

                    val authResponse = userLogin(sessionID,authorityID,userName!!,password!!,loginType)

                if(authResponse.Result){
                    isLoading.value=false
                    val domainResponse=getDomain(location)
                    **`val getUserResponse`** = getUser(authResponse.authorizeSessionModel!!.ID,"Bearer "+domainResponse.getDomainModel.ApiKey)
                    if (getUserResponse.result){
                        isSuccessfull.value=true
                        getUserResponseMutable.value=getUserResponse
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(view.context, "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    val intent = Intent(view.context,HomeActivity::class.java)
                    view.context.startActivity(intent)
                }else{
                    isLoading.value=false
                    Toast.makeText(view.context, "Login Failed!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
           }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(view.context, "Kullanıcı adı ve şifre boş bırakılamaz!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
}


suspend fun userLogin(
SessionID : Int,
AuthorityID: Int,
UserName: String,
Password : String,
LoginType: String
)= withContext(Dispatchers.IO){authorizeSessionRepository.userLogin(SessionID, AuthorityID, UserName, Password, LoginType)}

suspend fun getUser(
id: Int,
authorization : String
)= withContext(Dispatchers.Main){getUserRepository.getUser(id,authorization)}

suspend fun getDomain(
Location: String
)= withContext(Dispatchers.IO){getDomainRepository.getDomain(Location)}

}
```

i need to get **getUserResponse** variable in my AddressBook Fragment like this ;

```
package com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.ui.addressbook

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.R
import com.tolgahantutar.bexworkfloww.ui.auth.AuthViewModel
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class AdressBookFragment : Fragment() {
    private val addressBookViewModel : AdressBookViewModel by viewModels()
    private val authViewModel : AuthViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.adress_book_fragment, container, false)
    }
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        //addressBookViewModel.getContact(2,authViewModel.userResponseDelegate!!.getUserValue.apiKey)
     authViewModel.getUserResponseMutable.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
         if (it.result){
             Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "asdadasd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }
     })
        addressBookViewModel.isSuccessfull.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "ContactList Get Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

but observe is always null how can i get that getUserResponse inside my AddressBookFragment ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AuthViewModel` is most likely destroyed when you leave your `AuthFragment` (which I assume you have), so your `AdressBookFragment` is getting a new instance of the ViewModel, which doesn't retain any data from the previous screen.

I'd recommend that you store the result from `AuthViewModel` into a Repository or some other global state object and retrieve it from there.

ViewModels hold temporary data needed for a screen, but whether the user is authenticated matters to the whole application, not just a single screen. As such it should be stored someplace that lives for as long as the whole app, and is reachable from anywhere, like a Repository.

Comment: Sir, you are awesome! You explained it so understandable and it gave me an idea so i solved the problem. Thanks for this great answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
private val authViewModel : AuthViewModel by viewModels()
```

is equivalent to

```
private val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this).get(AuthViewModel::class.java)
}
```

So as you can see `this` is passed as `viewModelStoreOwner`.
Since i guess that you do net use `AdressBookFragment` as `viewModelStoreOwner` in your other fragment you are creating a new `viewmodel` in this fragment.

You probably need a shared viewmodel which you get when you use

```
private val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(AuthViewModel::class.java)
}
```

in both fragments

Comment: I got your point but now i realized that the first owner is not fragment but activity.Also i tried this way but it still not working

Comment: do your fragments live in the same activity ?

Comment: Yes they do exactly

Comment: did you also change the initialiation of the viewmodel in your other fragment? it also needs activity as viewmodelstoreowner

Comment: I solved the problem by creating a singleton repository class and then call that class in my fragment. Thank you for the answer